# Why iOS 7 modify my textField's border on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitextfield

i'm setting up borders on my texfields. I put them without borders on

```
[self.localeField.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[self.localeField.layer setBorderColor: [[NVGlobals border4MEColor] CGColor]];
[self.localeField.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
```

The problem is that between iphone and iPad app, the textfield has different border:

correct iPhone view:

[image]

wrong iPad view:

[image]

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your border width is 0.5.  I'm guessing your iPhone is a retina device whereas your iPad is not.  With subpixel sizing on a standard (non retina based) device visual effects gets hairy.  I'd avoid it if possible.

Try:

```
[self.localeField.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]];
```

Comment: woha, i'm surprised. Many thanks, monday when i go back to work i'll try it!